# The difference between const int and int literal

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to learn about `auto`, but some questions confused me. For example:

```
const int ci=0;
auto &g=ci;
auto &h=42;
```

Why is the second line right while the third line is wrong?

Comment: `ci` is an lvalue of type `const int`.  42 is a prvalue of type `int`.  The type deduction is different.

Comment: Beware of trying too hard to find the logic behind all C++ choices. The assumption that logic is the main drive behind the design of C++ is just wrong. In quite a few places, unfortunately, you just need to know "how" C++ is defined... asking yourself "why" can be a waste of time because there's no real (logic) reason indeed.

Comment: @6502 It totally is. Can you come up with one aspect design of C++ which is arbitrary?

Comment: @AimanAl-Eryani: the list is huge. One I find very arbitrary is the fact that any integer constant expression that evaluates to 0 can be implicitly converted to the null pointer (including `'\0'`, `(1-1)`, `!!!1`) where it could have been more logically just for 0 integer literals instead. One I find most annoying is for example the choice of an `unsigned` type for container size... there are historical explanations, but given the C++ semantic for `unsigned` it makes no sense at all from a language design point of view. Another nonsense is the priority of bit-wise operations... etc. etc.

Comment: @6502 You're talking about `NULL` which was replaced by `nullptr` in C++11. `nullptr` is always regarded as a pointer.  About container sizes, don't you mean `size_t`? I'd have considered it to be a waste of space for a signed type like `int` to hold the size value, simply because containers can't have a negative size.  As for bit-wise operators precedence over `==`, then this goes back to justified historical reasons: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194635/why-do-bitwise-operators-have-lower-priority-than-comparisons

Comment: @6502 And regardless, if you're mixing between bitwise, arithmetic operators and logical operators in the same level in the expression, then you're already doing a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a reference or a pointer to an r-value. An r-value is one which doesn't persist beyond a single expression. r-values can only appear at the right side of an assignment. l-values, on the other hand, do remain there available for access/use AND can appear at either left or right of an assignment.

```
42 = 1; //error. 42 is an r-value
someVariable = 1; //no problem, someVariable is an l-value
std::cout << &someVariable; // prints out the address of the variable as it's an l-value
std::cout << &42; // 42 was just created on the spot, and will disappear after this line. therefore, you can't have a pointer to it (or in short, it's an r-value)
```

`auto &h` declares a reference, but since `42` is an r-value, it can't be referenced for the same reason there can't be a pointer to it. `ci` is still an l-value despite it being declared `const`.